# Android - Imageview Fragment laggy

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, imageview

Hi I have a swipe view with corresponding tabs using fragments. The first view only contains a full hd image in the size of about 1.91mb.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/my_picture"
    android:src="@drawable/image1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now when I swipe from Page 1 to Page 2 or the other Way around the animation seems really laggy.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Tab_one();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Tab_two();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Tab_three();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new Tab_one();
            break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

So the transition from page1(contains only the imageview) to page2(contains a few textviews with information) is laggy. Can someone help me there? And does the filesize promote the lagging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image size is not important, your image resolution is important because in order to show an image for example in `ARGB_8888` format each pixel will take 4 bytes so quick analyses will yield :

image with different size:

```
image: 1024 * 768 * 4 = 2MB 
image: 1920 * 1080* 4 = 6MB
image: 1280 * 720 * 4 = 3MB
```

and in your computer all of them might be less than 1 MB. so what should you do? you must scale down your image and then assign to your image view, take a look at

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

you can use `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)` to loading your image.

Comment: Thanks this seems like a viable solution. Only thing would be that I want the image to fill the view below the actionbar. Meaning the width and height would be different for every device. Do you suggest reading out the dimensions of the screen and then using them with decodesampledbitmap* ?

Comment: yes, get the dimension of your `ImageView` and then set your image withe the `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource`.

Comment: Alright I did all that. Setting the Image via ImageView.setBitmapImage. But the transition from fragment1 to fragment2 still lags. Any suggestions?

Comment: How big your image? change `int inSampleSize = 1;` to `int inSampleSize = 4;` or above like 8, 16,... it is multiplied by 2.

Comment: Thanks :D I changed it to 4 and that solved the problem. no more lagging at all. at least on my htc one m8. what exactly is the insamplesize?
My picture was 1920x1080 and about 2mb, in jpeg.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize